# how to disable inheriting style from other div?

Tags: html, css

hi i have three input field  when i use these field seperately i'm seeing a normal input fields. Here it is

```
<div id="test">
<ul>
    <li> field1 <input type="text" name="n1"  value=""></li>
    <li> field2 <input type="text" name="n2"   value=""></li> 
    <li> field3 <textarea name="mes" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea></li> 
    <li><input type="submit" name="s" value="submit"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

when i use this things inside some other div i'm experiencing very large input fields and names(text).i guess this is inheriting size from other divs.i don't know what happening here.
i want it to be normal as it was when used separately even if i put it inside another div.What should i do for that. Thanks

Comment: first check is ther any css for div alone or input alone..

Comment: Please describe what makes you think the effect is caused by inheritance. Posting a sample document that actually illustrates the effect would be useful. Note that an element can inherit only from its parent, so a `div` or anything inside it cannot ever possibly inherit anything e.g. from a sibling of the `div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot disable inheriting styles as of now, what you can do is override these styles..

```
<div id="test" class="override">
   <ul>
      <li> field1 <input type="text" name="n1" value=""></li>
      <li> field2 <input type="text" name="n2" value=""></li> 
      <li> field3 <textarea name="mes" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea></li> 
      <li><input type="submit" name="s" value="submit"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test.override input[type=text] {
  /* Override here */
}
```

Am using `#test.override` so that specificity gets higher..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPLxH/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPLxH/1/) (Override in action)

Comment: @Alien same for text area? Like input[type=textarea] ?

Comment: @sun yes.. it applies to any element you want to override

Comment: So this way ul remains same. it won't affect other, Looks like this is the best way i should use whenever want to escape from inheriting problem. am i clear?

Comment: @sun if you don't specify styles for ul li, it will remain same, it will override only for the elements you specify to override, depends on your selectors, in my selector, am only selecting textboxes there

Comment: @alien clear.is this #1 way to do this.any other there?just want to know

Answer (score 1):

Just put width: auto; property to your inputs in css , this will prevent inheriting.